# Visual Studio 2010 - Post-build event - cd "$(ProjectDir)" exits with code 1 when project is loaded from a network drive

Tags: visual-studio-2010, post-build-event, cd, network-drive

I have a solution running in Visual Studio 2010 SP1.

As part of the solution I have a post-build event where the first line is:
   cd "$(ProjectDir)"
   ...

The post build event works fine when the project is loaded locally.

I have setup my laptop with the TFS workspace mapped to a network drive.  The solution builds and the website runs just fine - except for the features relying on the post-build event.  I have removed all of the Post-build event except the change directory line.

This is the error I get when I build:   The command "cd "\\[ComputerName]\b$[ProjectPath]\"" exited with code 1.

The solution is residing solely on the network drive, and it build and runs.  I can navigate to the directory in an explorer window without any problems (I saved the network credentials).

The only thing I can find through searching is that exit code 1 means that the path is incorrect, but I can copy and paste the path from the error into an explorer window and browse the directory on the network drive.

Any ideas why the change directory command wont work?

Comment: Not sure if this helps or not, but what .NET version are you using? I know certain versions, I think 3.5 and below, do not allow commands to run across the network by default - the framework needs "full trust" to run.

Comment: The project is .NET 4.0 with Mvc 3, but I also have 4.5 and Mvc 4 installed on the machine (for other projects). 

The computer is running Windows 8 with all Windows Updates installed.

Comment: Are you trying to execute a CD \\server\share command?

Comment: The box is one of my boxes and the hard drive is internal, but shared.

If the box name was "Foo" and the code located at "B:\Bar\Baz\"

Then the path would be "\\Foo\b$\Bar\Baz\"

Comment: CD is a command used by your shell command interpreter (CMD.EXE). Have you tried what is the response of you command prompt when you try to execute a CD \\server\share ?

Comment: When I run the command manually from a command prompt I get this message:  CMD does not support UNC paths as current directories.

I believe the problem is with \\BoxName.

The command prompt does like the \\.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CD is a command used by your shell command interpreter (CMD.EXE).
You cannot pass a `CD \\server\share` command to CMD.EXE.

Instead I suggest to map your share name to a drive letter like (from the command prompt)

```
NET USE Z: \\server\share /PERSISTENT:YES
```

Now you could write a batch file that uses your Z: drive and executes the commands required

For example

```
CD Z:\projectfolder\bin\release
copy *.exe z:\projectfolder\distribution /Y
```

You could also pass the predefined macros to this batch file as arguments and use them inside the batch file.

Comment: Thanks for your help.  I mapped the network drive in File Explorer and used the mapped drive.